# Schedule a cronjob start everyday automatically

Tags: rsync, crontab, cronjob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to have Linux run a command every X minutes?](https://superuser.com/questions/202127/is-there-a-way-to-have-linux-run-a-command-every-x-minutes)

I want to run a command which will be synchronize my remote folder data to my local computer.
command is **sync -ave 'ssh -p 22' root@prime-focos.com:/home/home/home/Prime_Office/Medienarchiv/EPaper/India_avg_sync /home/home/Test_anuragvijaya**

this is the command which I want to run everyday on a particular time. is it possible that I will schedule this command. so it will automatically run on a particular time. like i want to run this command daily at 10 am morning.

please suggest me how to write the program for this job.

Comment: You make it a cronjob, as you said in your title (and the tags). I'm missing the question here. Did you experience any problems while setting up your cronjob?

Comment: I know it can be possible with cronjob but i am not familiar with linux. so if you write how to do it. it is easy for me to compete.

Comment: Sorry, but there are so many resources out there on how to create cronjobs… We do require questions to show some effort into solving a problem yourself. Please read [ask] for more info. Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before posting?

Comment: Well, I had written up a really nice answer with steps and all. But then it got closed. me.likeSuperUser--;

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first putting that command into a bash script. Then, add this to your crontab:

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: thanks. actually i am not much familiar with linux. can you explain how to write a bash script.

Comment: You don't need to put the command in a script—you can run it straight from the crontab. @AnonymousAnurag, this is something you might want to look up in a tutorial or two. This is a very basic thing you should be able to find out quite easily when you search online.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just put your command in a file and save it somewhere. Then you could just put that whole line as something like: `0 10 * * * /usr/bin/bash /path/to/your/script` @slhck: I generally like them in scripts to help keep my crontab cleaner, but it's up to him.